# OpenMP, Simple for loop comparing values in array + counter

Tags: parallel-processing, openmp

So, I have this piece of code and I don't really now why it doesnt work properly.

```
#pragma omp parallel for 
for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    if (visible[i] > visible[i-1]) counter++;
}
```

I have an array that is ascendingly ordered and i want to count value changes. So from: 0.5 0.5 0.66 0.66 0.66 0.7 ... counter=2. 
However I if I simply use just this code the counter doesnt return right value and it also slower than withou pragma directive. (40ms without pragma, 45ms - 50ms with pragma, 32 000 000 iterations). I tried adding

```
#pragma omp atomic
counter++;
```

which returns right value, but the time is like 90ms. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm not sure it will ultimately lead to any sort of speed-up, but you need to declare `reduction(+:counter)` to make your code valid without the `atomic` directive

Comment: I actually redesigned my algorithem, but thanks nonetheless :)